# Open new tab in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a simple google extension that will upon clicking "ctrl+alt+x" search for the selected text in google.

This is my mainfest:

```
{
  "name": "A jQuery Chrome extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Use jQuery to build Chrome extensions",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "jquery.hotkeys.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

And this is my content.js:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+x', function() {

    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

    if (selectedText)
    {
        var googleQuery = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + selectedText;
        alert(googleQuery);
        chrome.tabs.create({"url" : googleQuery});  
        alert(googleQuery);
    }
});
```

The code works until the line for opening a new tab (the first alert pops up but not the second). I just can't seem to get it working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Google Chrome Content Scripts reference](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), `chrome.tabs` (and everything but `chrome.extension`) is not available to content scripts.

As an alternative, you could try [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open), or use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to let your background page to open the tab.

Comment: Thx, I useed message passing. It worked like a charm. I can now google selected text only by pressing ctrl+alt+x :)